# How to send emails from a server

Tags: 16.04, email

I have an Ubuntu server and I'd like to be able to send emails to gmail accounts.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: using a email client like Thunderbird would be your best bet

Comment: @Jack Please clarify. Do you wish to use a GUI-based app, or a non-GUI app, to send mail from that server? If you have a GUI installed, you can use GUI apps such as Thunderbird, or use a web browser (Firefox, Chromium, Waterfox, et al.) to access Gmail's web interface at www.gmail.com . Do you want the email of other users on attached PCs to be able to send email through the server? Please click [edit] and advise what you want. And, we don't discuss 'best ways'; that's asking for an opinion, which we don't do. https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @wraith3690001 Ubuntu servers don't have any GUI. Thunderbird is neither included nor will it run on a default server installation.

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu servers have whatever one installed, which could perfectly be a desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have many solution possible for me i use [Msmtp client](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) and [heirloom-mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html)

make sure to update repository index first before installing msmtp-mta heirloom-mailx

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install msmtp-mta
$ sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx
```

configure msmtp by adding your credentials connection details check the tuto [How to use Gmail from the Ubuntu Terminal to send Emails](https://vitux.com/how-to-use-gmail-from-the-ubuntu-terminal-to-send-emails/)
 it explain it in more detail and better than me